# Connection between a like in Facebook and the ads in Youtube

Tags: facebook, youtube, facebook-like, ads

Maybe someone here can answer my question.
Is it possible that the items which I liked in Facebook will appear to me in Youtube advertisments ? 
In general my question is : Is it possible that information about me and my actions in Facebook eventually might transmit to Youtube ?
Thank you for your help !

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with programming.

Answer (score 0):

Depends what action you perform on Facebook. If you are interacting with your friends content "organic" that activity will be only in Facebook and not available on external advertisers on sites like Youtube.

In a scenario like : 
1) you saw a friend posting about an product
2) you liked or comment on his post
3) you searched that product on Amazon
the amazon activity can be hint of your interest and can determine Amazon to advertise(re-target) on channels like youtube to convince you buy that product